# Retain additional variable while joining multiple dataframes with dplyr

Tags: join, dplyr

I have to combine values for a given variable `gfr` from several dataframes. I have two datasets, `x1` which contains `gfr` and `date` and additional columns (around 50 in the real dataset) which should be carried along, and additional values for `gfr` and `date`  in a dataset called `x2`.

```r
library(dplyr)

x1 <- tribble(
  ~id,    ~gfr,         ~date,  ~additional_info, 
     1,     90,  "2019-01-01",                12, 
     2,     80,  "2019-02-01",                13, 
     3,    120,  "2019-03-01",                14
)


x2 <- tribble(
  ~id,   ~gfr,         ~date, 
    1,     90,  "2019-01-01",  
    1,     45,  "2018-01-01",  
    2,     80,  "2019-02-01",  
    2,     60,  "2019-03-01", 
    4,     40,  "2018-02-01", 
    5,     60,  "2018-03-01"
)
```

Just using `left_join` is not "catching" the new information from `x2`:

```r
left_join(x1, x2)

#> Joining, by = c("id", "gfr", "date")
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>      id   gfr date       additional_info
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                <dbl>
#> 1     1    90 2019-01-01              12
#> 2     2    80 2019-02-01              13
#> 3     3   120 2019-03-01              14
```

Using `full_join` (1) adds additional ids that are not in `x1` and (2) doesn't keep the `additional_info` for all observations:

```r
full_join(x1, x2)  

#> Joining, by = c("id", "gfr", "date")
#> # A tibble: 7 x 4
#>      id   gfr date       additional_info
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                <dbl>
#> 1     1    90 2019-01-01              12
#> 2     2    80 2019-02-01              13
#> 3     3   120 2019-03-01              14
#> 4     1    45 2018-01-01              NA
#> 5     2    60 2019-03-01              NA
#> 6     4    40 2018-02-01              NA
#> 7     5    60 2018-03-01              NA
```

The dataframe that I want looks like this:

```r
wanted <- tribble(
  ~id, ~gfr,        ~date, ~additional_info,
    1,   90, "2019-01-01",               12,
    1,   45, "2018-01-01",               12,
    2,   80, "2019-02-01",               13,
    2,   60, "2019-03-01",               13,
    3,  120, "2019-03-01",               14
)
```

I can get there with a long pipe:

```r
full_join(x1, x2) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(additional_info = first(additional_info)) %>% 
  distinct_at(vars(c(gfr, date)), .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  filter(id %in% x1$id) %>% 
  arrange(id, date)

#> Joining, by = c("id", "gfr", "date")
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#> # Groups:   id [3]
#>      id   gfr date       additional_info
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                <dbl>
#> 1     1    45 2018-01-01              12
#> 2     1    90 2019-01-01              12
#> 3     2    80 2019-02-01              13
#> 4     2    60 2019-03-01              13
#> 5     3   120 2019-03-01              14
```

But I am sure there's an easier solution. Thanks in advance!

<sup>Created on 2019-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

After some more "fiddling" around with dplyr, I found some code which works and is easy to read, but still a bit klunky. I'll post it here, so anyone can use that approach until someone else has a better answer:

```r
library(dplyr)


x1 <- tribble(
  ~id,    ~gfr,         ~date,  ~additional_info, 
  1,     90,  "2019-01-01",                12, 
  2,     80,  "2019-02-01",                13, 
  3,    120,  "2019-03-01",                14
)


x2 <- tribble(
  ~id,   ~gfr,         ~date, 
  1,     90,  "2019-01-01",  
  1,     45,  "2018-01-01",  
  2,     80,  "2019-02-01",  
  2,     60,  "2019-03-01", 
  4,     40,  "2018-02-01", 
  5,     60,  "2018-03-01"
)
```

Extract the "stem" of my dataframe

```r
base <- x1 %>% select(-gfr, -date)
```

combine `x1` and `x2` and use only distinct values before joining

```r
comb <- x1 %>% 
  select(id, gfr, date) %>% 
  full_join(x2) %>% 
  distinct()
#> Joining, by = c("id", "gfr", "date")
```

Then use a simple `left_join`:

```r
left_join(base, comb)
#> Joining, by = "id"
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>      id additional_info   gfr date      
#>   <dbl>           <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     
#> 1     1              12    90 2019-01-01
#> 2     1              12    45 2018-01-01
#> 3     2              13    80 2019-02-01
#> 4     2              13    60 2019-03-01
#> 5     3              14   120 2019-03-01
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Any easier ways to do this with dplyr?